# кнопка закрыть свернуть и развернуть

Tags: windows

как сделать чтобы кнопки закрыть свернуть и развернуть при наваедении на них курсор, выделялась красным квадратом?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть у меня выделяется только контур, а не как показано на этой картинке из гугла
h t t p s ://  go   o.    g  l / MSKmlK
wind 8.1 у меня.....как можно это дело изменить
может быть есть какой нибудь дизайн, чтобы выделения были бы красным?

Comment: На чем пишите хоть?

Comment: @AGS17 всмысле на чем?